# pfSense - handling public IP addresses as a Internal range

Tags: networking, router, routing, pfsense

I recently bought 1Gbps internet access in my business and /24 public IP address for internal use.

My 2911 Cisco router doesn't seem to be handling that speed Internet, so I setup pfSense machine as a router and working great.

However, when I check whatismyip.com website to check source IP address, it is replaced by the IP address provided by Internet Service Provider.

Source IP address was mine when I used the Cisco router, but it replaced after using pfSense.

Is there a way to keep my public /24 IP address to the Internet?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

That IP address is given by the provider. If you wish to change it, you need to contact them.

Comment: I see my public IP addresses on whatismyip.com website when I use the Cisco router but not when using pfSense. I was wondering if there is a setting in pfSense to keep the source IP address that I purchased.

Comment: oh! You can change the WAN settings on your pfsense, set a static IP address and use one that you purchased.